# How to use distribution push certificate in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

What steps do I need to do to be able to debug the app using a distribution push certificate?

We currently have an app already published into the app store and the server is using a distribution certificate. However, when I run the app from Xcode, it uses a development certificate. This means that I cannot receive pushes, and therefore cannot debug issues related to pushes.

What and where do I need to set something, so that Xcode starts using the distribution push certificate?

Xcode version is 12.4

Comment: AFAIK, only the bundleId of the app needs to match with the bundleId the cert uses. Do you have different bundleIds between debug and release certs?

Comment: No, bundle IDs are the same when working with Xcode and when publishing. Its tedious to set up secondary server for apple sandbox endpoint for each and every project we do, so i am trying to find a way to debug already submited app using a production server, so we can get away without secondary servers. But so far if i run app from XCode it expects to work with apple sandbox push service and if production server generates pushes, Xcode app will not receive it.

Answer (score 0):

here are the stepps I take to create certificates and Provisioning Profiles for APNS.

[Thankful they kept this amazing Ray Wenderlich post alive](https://www.cnblogs.com/greywolf/p/3476634.html)

The steps are the same for development and distribution.

Edit: if you made the APNS switch successfully from port 2195 to the new port 443 I'd love to learn how! Still getting command line errors when testing a connection using the generated SSL certificate.